# I want perform sum of product of two elements at differnt levels

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I tried for following code but its not working. I have taken one string and write XSLT in it and load it  XslCompiledTransform object.

```
 <xsl:sequence select=
        "sum(//Item/(cost * related_id/Item/quantity))"/>
```

Source XML:

```
<AML>
  <Item>
    <cost>
      40
    </cost>
    <related_id>
      <Item>
        <quantity>2</quantity>
      </Item>
    </related_id>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <cost>
      50
    </cost>
    <related_id>
      <Item>
        <quantity>10</quantity>
      </Item>
    </related_id>
  </Item>
</AML>
```

Comment: `xsl:sequence` is an XSLT 2.0 feature and XslCompiledTransform only supports XSLT 1.0. What does your source XML look like?

Comment: My Source XML is look like:                                                    `<AML> <Item><cost>40<cost><related_id>                                      <Item><quantity>2</quantity></Item>                        </related_id></Item>                                                 <Item><cost>50<cost><related_id>                                      <Item><quantity>10</quantity></Item>                        </related_id></Item>                                                                      </AML>`

Comment: so what i suppose to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in the comments, `xsl:sequence` and that XPath syntax you're trying to use aren't available in XSLT 1.0 (which XslCompiledTransform uses), but you can achieve a sum of formulas by using a recursive template:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:call-template name="SumSet">
      <xsl:with-param name="items" select="/*/Item" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="SumSet">
    <xsl:param name="items" />

    <xsl:if test="$items">
      <xsl:variable name="currentValue">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$items[1]" />
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:variable name="remainderSum">
        <xsl:call-template name="SumSet">
          <xsl:with-param name="items" select="$items[position() > 1]" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:variable>

      <xsl:value-of select="$currentValue + $remainderSum"/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="not($items)">0</xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Item">
    <xsl:value-of select="cost * related_id/Item/quantity"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When this is run on your input XML, the result is:

```
580
```

That would be the generic approach, but since you've mentioned that you're using XslCompiledTransform, you can use `msxsl:node-set()` to simplify this task a bit:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
  <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="values">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="/*/Item" />
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:value-of select="sum(msxsl:node-set($values)/*)"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Item">
    <itemValue>
      <xsl:value-of select="cost * related_id/Item/quantity"/>
    </itemValue>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This also produces the value `580` when run on your input XML.