# I want sum of product of two element

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I am have xml . I using following XPath expression:

`sum(//Item[@type='sg_aml_rel'][(./sg_percentage * ./related_id/Item[@type='sg_aml2']/sg_cost)])`

I have created object of XMLDoucment and Load XML into it then created XPathNavigator object and provide xpth to evaluate method of XPathNavigator.
 My XML look Like:

```
<AML>
   <Item>
       <sg_percentage>10</sg_percentage>
       <related_id>
          <Item>
           <sg_cost>100<sg_cost>
          </Item>
       <related_id>    
   </Item>
  <Item>
       <sg_percentage>20</sg_percentage>
       <related_id>
          <Item>
           <sg_cost>500<sg_cost>
          </Item>
       <related_id>    
   </Item>
<AML>
```

I want SUM(sg_percentage*sg_cost).

Comment: @DanielHaley: That duplicate isn't of any value - it was closed as a NARQ, and has 7 downvotes.

Comment: @JonEgerton - You're right. I must have pasted the wrong URL. This user has posted this question 4 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I [already provided you an answer to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14750840/i-want-perform-sum-of-product-of-two-elements-at-differnt-levels) when you asked about it in reference to XSLT. Without custom extensions, there is no way to do this with a single XPath 1.0 expression.  Your best bet is to do something like the following:

```
decimal sum = 0;
foreach (XPathNavigator item in document.CreateNavigator().Select("/AML/Item"))
{
    sum += Convert.ToDecimal(item.Evaluate("sg_percentage * related_id/Item/sg_cost"));
}
```

When this is finished, `sum` should have the value you're looking for.

One way to genericize this a bit is to define a method like this:

```
public static decimal SumPaths(XmlNode source, string nodePath, string formula)
{
    decimal sum = 0;
    foreach (XPathNavigator item in source.CreateNavigator().Select(nodePath))
    {
        sum += Convert.ToDecimal(item.Evaluate(formula));
    }
    return sum;
}
```

And then you can call it like this:

```
decimal sum = 
     SumPaths(document, "/AML/Item", "sg_percentage * related_id/Item/sg_cost");
```

Comment: this is working but i want generic approach so that i can put any xpath and it will provide me output of xpath. How can write this generic code.please provide somr suggetions. thanks

Comment: As I've already said, this can't be computed with a single XPath unless you use non-standard XPath functions (which can be fairly complicated).  I've modified my answer to provide a generic method for computing the sum of a certain formula across several nodes.